# Find and replace text in custom format text with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, replace, text-files

i have to edit a .txt file that is formatted in a particular format. I can upload the file through ajax, but when I try to use .replace to edit the string, I get the error which is not a function. How can I resolve to edit this type of file? thanks in advance to all!

```
 $.ajax({
    url : "/nicnt.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success : function (datafile) { 
        fileContents = datafile.toString().Replace("UCOMPANY","CHANGE TEXT");
        alert(fileContents);
    }
});
```

this is the file structure load in a text area:

```
/\ NI FC MTD  /\1.0��<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<ProductHints spec="1.0.9">

  <Product version="1">
    <Company>UCOMPANY</Company>
    <Name>UNAME</Name>
    <RegKey>UKEY</RegKey>
    <Type>Content</Type>
    <PoweredBy>Kontakt</PoweredBy>
    <Icon>kontakt</Icon>
    <Visibility>1</Visibility>
    <AuthSystem>RAS2</AuthSystem>
    <SNPID>USN</SNPID>
    <ProductSpecific>
      <Visibility type="Number">3</Visibility>
    </ProductSpecific>
  </Product>

</ProductHints>
/\ NI FC MTD  /\��������H�/\ NI FC TOC  /\.db.cacheH���������/\ NI FC TOC  /\<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<soundinfos version="110">
  <all/>
</soundinfos>
```

Comment: Its actually [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) lowercase not `Replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.replace` instead of `.Replace`
camelCase is used everywhere in JavaScript

Comment: Oh my God! thank you for this answer and forgive my question, but I was absolutely not aware of this writing error. I had entered a vortex of assumptions, between encodings etc., instead it was closer than I thought.